# JSON Parse in python (special case)

Tags: python, json

My project is receiving a JSON message which look like this:

```
"listinginfo":{
    "438317215072450609":{
        "listingid":"438317215072450609",
        "price":27044,
        "fee":4056,
    },
    "428184115913903011":{
        "listingid":"428184115913903011",
        "price":480,
        "fee":72,
    }
}
```

In this json file, I want to get "438317215072450609" and "428184115913903011".
I've tried :

```
myjson.get('listinginfo').get(*).get(listingid)
#and
myjson['listinginfo'][0]['listingid']
```

But of course, it doesn't work ;)
Thank you in advance (sorry for this bad english)

Comment: What do you mean with *"not work"*? And did you convert the json string into a python data structure already? This is not valid json, so I guess that's your first problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have those values twice: once as the key in the outer dict, and once as the `listingid` value inside the inner dict. To get the first, you can just do:

```
myjson['listinginfo'].keys()
```

and to get the second, you can do:

```
[d['listingid'] for d in myjson['listinginfo'].values()]
```

If they're always the same, of course, it doesn't matter which of these you use.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your "JSON" string valid JSON by surrounding it with `{` and `}` and removing the trailing commas in the inner objects. I edited the string by hand instead of with code, because this should really be fixed in the code *producing* that "JSON".

```
myjson = '''{"listinginfo":{
                "438317215072450609":{
                    "listingid":"438317215072450609",
                    "price":27044,
                    "fee":4056
                },
                "428184115913903011":{
                    "listingid":"428184115913903011",
                    "price":480,
                    "fee":72
                }
            }}'''
```

Then turn the string into a python data structure:

```
import json
data = json.loads(myjson)
```

Then extract what you want:

```
ids = data['listinginfo'].keys()
```

Or if the ID is not always also the key of the object:

```
ids = [d['listingid'] for d in data['listinginfo'].values()]
```

Comment: Thank you ! ids = data['listinginfo'].keys() work ! That exactly what i wanted !